# bash's builtin time accepts %E - what's going on?

Tags: bash, time

The bash man page lists three and only three format codes recognized by the shell's builtin version of `time`: `%R` for the real time, `%U` for the time spent in userspace, and `%S` for time spent in system calls. So the following behavior is confusing to say the least:

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
$ TIMEFORMAT="%E %P"
$ time sleep 1
1.002 0.00
```

Clearly something is being left out of the man page. The builtin `time` is recognizing `%E` and `%P`. However I checked all other uppercase and lowercase letters and none of them are recognized, except `l` as a modifier:

```
$ TIMEFORMAT="%lE %lS %lU %lR"
$ time sleep 1
0m1.001s 0m0.000s 0m0.000s 0m1.001s
```

I'm curious to understand what's going on here - is this really just an omission in the man page, or is there something weird about my bash? Ideally, can anyone point me to some documentation that explains this? I'm using bash 4.2.48(1) on Gentoo amd64 stable, if it matters.

Comment: BTW, man pages are generally describe the implementation fairly well but only the actual code if the final authority as to options and how something operates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [section of `execute_cmd.c` of `bash-4.2+dfsg`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?id=f281b8f4f8936b2713966274d9f8508a9f0910e4#n1147) that deals with `TIMEFORMAT`:

```
if (*s == 'R' || *s == 'E')
  len = mkfmt (ts, prec, lng, rs, rsf);
else if (*s == 'U')
  len = mkfmt (ts, prec, lng, us, usf);
else if (*s == 'S')
  len = mkfmt (ts, prec, lng, ss, ssf);
else
  {
    internal_error (_("TIMEFORMAT: `%c': invalid format character"), *s);
    free (str);
    return;
  }
```

So, from the above, it appears that `%E` means the same as `%R`: elapsed (real) time.

I have seen something similar in GNU `sed`.  The `-r` option is documented as enabling sed's extended regular expressions.  An undocumented feature is that `-E` does the same thing.  In this case, the purpose is clear: this provides compatibility with the flag that BSD `sed` uses for extended regex.  One possible reason for keeping it undocumented would be that it allows GNU the option to use `-E` for something else in the future.  The reasons for allowing `%E` in TIMEFORMAT but keeping it undocumented might be similar.

Comment: Indeed! Though I'm pretty sure something is wrong (with the blame falling on the man page maintainers) if we really have to go to the source code to see the explanation for this.